# Remote installation of a deb package

Tags: software-installation

Is there a way to install a deb package "D" on a remote machine "M" without transferring "D" to "M"? If I move "D" to "M", the owner of the machine "M" can copy my deb package (before I finish installation) which is something that I don't want. I have developed the package "D" myself, so I don't want them to have it. And we do not have time/resources to add a license or key to our package.

Comment: Machine M will be able to read most of your data or code anyway. Consider DRM technologies

Comment: ^What they said. All the files in the package, and any maintainer scripts you have, will still be on the remote system, so they can trivially assemble a dpkg package themselves from all that.

Comment: More than trivially - there's already a debian package that'll do exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I have bad news for you.

[dpkg-repack](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=dpkg-repack) is a standard bit of software that uses the packaging info files (which *have* to remain on the system in order to make sure upgrade go properly) to rebuild the .deb package.

If you install  D on remote machine M, whoever has root on M can reconstruct D any time they like.

**EDIT** And even if you somehow prevent them from doing that, a simple `dpkg -L packagename` will tell them *exactly* which files are part of the package, at which point they can just tar those up and be done.

Comment: In most cases even non-root users can reconstruct packages.